# Define an object in a .cpp file

Tags: c++

Header file

```
class Universe
{
    public:
        Universe();
        ~Universe();

    private:
        ChunkManager chunkManager;
};
```

I want to initialize `chunkManger` without using the default constructor. However, the constructor I want to use takes an object. How do I make the `chunkManager` object to use the correct constructor in the .cpp file? So I want something like this:

```
Universe::Universe(){

    world = new b2World(b2Vec2(0, 0));
    world->SetAllowSleeping(false);

    //I want something like this because the constructor I want takes a World object
    chunkManager = new ChunkManager(world);

    player = new Player(world);
}
```

Comment: Why is this getting down voted? What did I do wrong?

Comment: plus one from my side. As u r trying to clear ur concept.

Comment: Where did world and player come from?  They are not in the header.  What are the oo relationships?  Should the universe contain exactly one world, one chunkmanager and one player?

Comment: @KennyOstrom The header file was much bigger, but I cut it down because I didn't think it was necessary, however there wasn't that much in the constructor so I just copy and pasted the whole thing

Comment: You already accepted an answer on the basic object vs pointer issue, so I'll assume you have the oo model under control.  Make sure you handle the cleanup correctly as well.  You need to make sure that the class definition makes it impossible for the cleanup to go wrong.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Oh! Thank you for reminding me! I forgot to destroy it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ChunkManager` in the header is an object not a pointer, so `chunkManager = new ChunkManager(world);` is wrong.

You can leave it as an object and initialize like this:

```
Universe::Universe() : chunkManager(world)
{
```

But you don't have `world` yet (unless you can pass it as a parameter). The easiest solution is to make the header have a pointer:

```
private:
        ChunkManager* chunkManager;
```

And then your .cpp is ok.

Edit: I assume what Kenny Ostram is getting at in the comments is that since you've dynamically allocated `chunkManager` you need to be sure you `delete` it at some point (probably the destructor) to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: Edit in the destructor for him, please.

Comment: He could write `Universe::Universe(): chunkManager(world = new b2World(b2Vec2(0, 0))){ ... }`